# Спарсить XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, синтаксический-анализ

На форме две кнопки. "Следующая запись" и "Предыдущая запись". Изначально когда запускаю прогу она вопрос записывает в Qtextbox1. А ответы соответственно Atextbox1,Atextbox2,Atextbox3 и т.д. Как при нажатии на кнопку данные из xml пихать на форму. Кажись надо юзать xptah. Но что то не осилил

```
<Key>
  first question
  <Value>answer1</Value> 
  <Value>answer2</Value> 
  <Value>answer3</Value> 
  <Value>answer4</Value> 
  <Value>answer5</Value> 
  </Key>
- <Key>
  second question
  <Value>answer1</Value> 
  <Value>answer2</Value> 
  <Value>answer3</Value> 
  </Key>
- <Key>
  third question
  <Value>answer1</Value> 
  <Value>answer2</Value> 
  <Value>answer3</Value> 
  </Key>
```

Comment: Эээ... а где ваш root-элемент?

Comment: Для того, чтобы на вопрос можно было ответить, добавьте *весь* относящийся к проблеме код и сообщения об ошибках в сам вопрос.  [ask], [Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, распарсьте данные:

```
class Record
{
    public string question;
    public IEnumerable<string> answers;
}

var xdoc = XDocument.Load(...);
var records = xdoc.Root.Elements("Key").Select(key =>
    new Record()
    {
        question = key.Nodes.First().Value,
        answers = key.Elements("Value").Select(e => (string)e)
    });
```

Затем можно их превратить в массив (`.ToString()`), и пользоваться текущим индексом.

Comment: @Donil: да, вы правы, в качестве DataContext'а можно указать XML и прибиндиться к нему, указывая XPath-выражения где нужно, в Binding'ах. Напишете пример?

Answer (score 1):

В WPF в качестве источника данных можно указать xml-файл. Вот простеникий пример:
Есть файл следующего содержания:

```
<root>
    <items>
        <item id="1">
            Item #1
        </item>
        <item id="2">
            Item #2
        </item>
    </items>
</root>
```

Чтобы получить данные, нужно описать XmlDataProvider, для удобства укажим его как DataContext нашего Grid'a:

```
<Grid.DataContext>
    <XmlDataProvider Source="test.xml" XPath="/root/items/item"/>
</Grid.DataContext>
```

И отобразим данные в ListView (в первый столбец отобразим атрибут "id", а во второй содержимое тега):

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath='@id'}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Content" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=.}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Где в XPath указываем то что хотим "достать", при этом нам доступна все прелести этого самого [XPath](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

P.S. Куда делся мой коментарий? Неужто сам грохнул? О_о